# Faster use of the cli - setting a variable for current project

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I'm frequently using the cli (terminal) on Linux and Mac.

How can I save time by setting a variable to the current project folder instead of

`cd path/to/folder/over/and/over/again`

Something like

`cd the-current-project`

(with tab completion)
?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your shell, you can set a `cdpath` with directories you regularly cd to, and so you can do just what you want:

```
cd the-current-project
```

from anywhere. See [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2005031814311425) for more details.

Alternatively you can just set a shell variable and

```
cd $CURRENT_PROJECT
```

Again, your shell will determine whether you can tab-complete this (I know `zsh` will do this. I'm not sure about `bash`).

Comment: +1, didn't know about `CDPATH`. Does it also work in conjunction with `pushd` and `popd`? So you `pushd` to a "favourite" in `CDPATH` then `popd` straight back to where you were?

Comment: It does (again, in zsh. Not sure about bash, ut I'd hope so)